# angularjs factory structure for several methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

ok, this is not actually the data that i use in my project but im simplifying it a little.

But i have this factory in my angularjs app:

```
myApp.factory('inputinfo', function () {


var self = {


    test: function (in) {
        return "hello " + in;
    }
    test2: function (in) {
        return "hello " + in;
    }


};

return { test: self.test, test2: self.test2 };

 });
```

that works ok, but what i want is to "combine" them. i mean right now im parsing the in parameter along with both test1 and test2 and i want them to use it from same function... so i tried something like this:

```
var self = {


    nfo: function (in) {

        var selfObj = { test1: test1(), test2: test2() };

        function test1() {
            return "hello " + in;
        }

        function test2() {
            return "hello " + in + " ok";
        }


        return { self: self.selfObj }


    }


};

return { nfo: self.nfo };
```

but that just returns undefined.

so to try to explain excatly what i wanna do:

say i call the inputinfo factory, i should be able to call and use it something like this:

```
var some = inputinfo.nfo("something");
```

and then i want to be able to do:

```
 alert(some.test1);
```

so i can keep getting all values (test1, test2 etc.) when i call some.

Im having trouble understanding how i need to write this to get the result i want. Sorry if i didnt explain it that well :-S

edit:

maybe to explain it in a simpler way:

say i have this:

```
function atest(in)
{

    var values = {
        one: function() {
           return "hello " + in;     
        }
        two: function() {
           return "hello " + in " ok";
        }
    }

    return { values: values };

}
```

with that i can do:

```
 var result = atest("something");
 alert(result.values.one());
```

so how to i structure that in a factiory to get the same result? (and to be able to call it the same way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok did something like this:

```
myApp.factory('inputinfo', function () {

    return function (in) {
     var self = {


        test: function () {
            return "hello " + in;
        },
        test2: function () {
            return "hello " + in;
        }


      };

      return self;

    }

}
```

And then i could call it like:

```
var test = inputinfo("dude");
alert(test.test());
```

that would give me the result: hello dude